# Error [Plugin.hh:127]

Tags: gazebo-1.9

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

**Hello Everyone**

I was working with this Tutorial and get the same error:

http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/1.3/controlrobot/mobilebase

Or

http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/1.3/controlrobot/mobilebase_laser

Get a similar error:

Error [Plugin.hh:127] Failed to load plugin libmypluginwithsensor.so: mypluginwithsensor.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Or

Error [Plugin.hh:127] Failed to load plugin libmy_plugin.so: libmy_plugin.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

And

libmypluginwithsensor.so

libmy_plugin.so

It's in ~/gazebo/my_plugin/build:

**A lot of Thanks!!**

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/4535/error-%5Bplugin.hh:127%5D/) by [vncntmh](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/376/vncntmh/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 80 on 2013-09-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The solve for this problem is because it's must export plugins and load the model from the package

Example:

My path is libmyplugin.so and this's In ~/gazebo/my_plugin/build

Before to get this path I used:

```
 cmake ..;make  //in the folder /build
```

I used:
cd ~/gazebo/my_plugin/build  //here is libmyplugin.so

```
 export GAZEBO_PLUGIN_PATH=`pwd`:$GAZEBO_PLUGIN_PATH  //with this instruction I load libmyplugin.so and it's prepared it for load the simulation
 gazebo
```

In my case I insert the robot from Gazebo

A lot of Thanks!!

---

Originally posted by [vncntmh](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/376/vncntmh/) with karma: 80 on 2013-10-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2